# youtube api v3 get related videos , max result not workig

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I tried this below but it returns only 4 , I need 50 ..how can i do that ?

```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=5rOiW_xY-kc&type=video&key={api-key}&max-results=50
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the parameter -- it should be maxResults, not max-results.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `max-results`, you need "maxResults":

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=5rOiW_xY-kc&type=video&key={api-key}&maxResults=50
```